# Visual studio 2017 Team foundation server question on checking whose working on what files

Tags: tfs

Let's say there is 2 members working on the project right now at the same time,
is there any functionality to check in real time who is working on which file?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can see who worked on which files from the History (Changeset for TFVC, Commit for Git).

For real-time checking, if you are using Git, as far as I know there isn't a way to see the information as it's distributed, you can only check the status from the local repository. Please see [Choosing the right version control for your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc?view=vsts) for details.

If you are using TFVC 'server workspace', you can check the information from Source Control Explorer.

Alternately you can use the tool called [**Team Foundation Sidekicks**](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) which is a suite of tools (includes Code Review Sidekick, Shelveset Sidekick, Labels Sidekick, History Sidekick, Workspace Sidekick and Status) for TFS administrators and advanced users providing rich GUI for administrative and advanced version control tasks, you can use it to check and track the things you required.

Unfortunately it's no available for VS 2017, the latest version 6.0 only works for VS 2015.

[image]

Comment: TFS Sidekicks is no longer available.