# TFS Get Workspaces With Pending Changes on PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tfs

I'm new at TFS, trying to get all the TFS workspaces with it's pending changes in local machine on PowerShell for administrative purpose.

I know you can get the workspaces using:

```
tf vc workspaces
```

And the something similar with pending changes:

```
tf vc  status
```

But, How can i get each workspaces with it's pending changes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below PowerShell script to get each workspace with it's pending changes:

```
#Set-Alias tf "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe" #For VS 2017

Set-Alias tf "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" #For Visual Studio 2015

Write-Host "Workspaces in current local machine:`n" 

tf workspaces

Write-Host "`n`nPending changes for each workspace:"

ForEach ($workspace in tf workspaces | Foreach {"$(($_ -split '\s+',2)[0])"} | select-string -Pattern 'Collection:|Workspace|""|----------------' -NotMatch )
{

Write-Host "Workspace Name:" $workspace
tf status /workspace:$workspace 
Write-Host `n 
}
```

Besides, you can also use the tool [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) to manage the workspaces and pending changes...  Reference my answer in another thread: [Visual studio 2017 Team foundation server question on checking whose working on what files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52466758/visual-studio-2017-team-foundation-server-question-on-checking-whose-working-on)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, i'll give it a shot.

Comment: In fact, it did works; there is also a plugin for visual studio 2017 that can do the job https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vercellone.TFSAutoShelveforVisualStudio2017